# android - How to make the selected url startpage of webview on next run?

Tags: android, webview

**I EDITED MY QUESTION**. I need to make the selected url startpage of webview on next run of application. i want use sharedpreferences, but im failing to do so. There is problem with another code inside activity, my code and that code wont work togather. i dont know what to add for more explanation, i hope guys you will understand my qeustion. i just need sharedpreferences code without changing the main code.
Below codes shouldnt be changed because if change it another activity which has a sharedpreferences will not work:

```
String current_page_url = "https://website.com/az";

startwebview();

webView.loadUrl(current_page_url);

public void startwebview(){
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadUrl("https://website.com/az");
```

Here is my main code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


private ProgressBar progressBar;

WebView webView;
String current_page_url = "https://website.com/az";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

startwebview();

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    initWebView();
    webView.loadUrl(current_page_url);

}

private void initWebView() {
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            current_page_url = url;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                webView.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });

   WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

}

 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.ru:
            webView.loadUrl("https://website.com/ru");

    ***i want add sharedpreferences here and save this page for startpage on next run of application***


            Toast.makeText(this, "Page 1 is set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.en:
            webView.loadUrl("https://website.com/en);

 ***i want add sharedpreferences here and save this page for startpage on next run of application***


            Toast.makeText(this, "Page 2 is set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    }

 }


  public void startwebview(){
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("https://website.com/az");
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to use shared preferences?

Comment: use only one switch statement

Comment: my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have, save your preference after select the webpage

```
switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.ru:
        webView.loadUrl("https://website.com/ru");

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
         editor.putString("url", "https://website.com/ru");
         editor.commit();


        Toast.makeText(this, "Page 1 is set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
}
switch (item.getItemId())
{
    case R.id.en:
        webView.loadUrl("https://website.com/en");

         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
         editor.putString("url", "https://website.com/en");
         editor.commit();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Page 2 is set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
}
```

Then read the preference on your onCreate method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

startwebview();
initWebView();

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredURL = prefs.getString("url", null);
if (restoredURL != null) {
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl(restoredURL);
}


}
```

Comment: sorry, but itsnot worked, because i have `String current_page_url = "https://website.com/az";`. and i have another code which used for bookmark, when i click urls which saved in bookmark its opening the website which u guide me `onOptionsItemSelected`. my bookmark codes and codes which you gave me its conflicted.

Answer (score 0):

to save last visited page

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.ru:{
            webView.loadUrl("https://website.com/ru");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Page 1 is set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString(WEB_LINKS, "https://website.com/ru");
            editor.commit();
            return true;}
        case R.id.en:{
            webView.loadUrl("https://website.com/en");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Page 2 is set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString(WEB_LINKS, "https://website.com/en");
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        }
        default: return false;
    }

}
```

to read last visited page

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String lastSavedPage = sharedPref.getString(WEB_LINKS,current_page_url);
```

if nothing is saved your default page will be https://website.com/az

Comment: Maybe working code, but for my issue unfortunately is not working, because i have set 
`String current_page_url = "https://website.com/az";

startwebview();

webView.loadUrl(current_page_url);

public void startwebview(){
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("https://website.com/az");
}`

These my main problems and they shouldnt be changed

Comment: change your oncreate method with this  `@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String lastSavedPage = sharedPref.getString(WEB_LINKS,"https://website.com/az");
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        initWebView();
        webView.loadUrl(lastSavedPage);

    } `

Comment: as i said its working code, but in my case its conflicted with another sharedpreferences. see my edited question, some code shoudnt be changed.

Comment: what part of your code you must not change? Explain briefly so I could help you

Comment: ok if so, just put my sharedprefrences code above ` webView.loadUrl(current_page_url); in oncreate method

Comment: I meant by sharedprefrences code this ` SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String lastSavedPage = sharedPref.getString(WEB_LINKS,current_page_url); `

Comment: then call webview.loadUrl(lastSavedPage);

Comment: `WEB_LINKS` is not reguired, this code is for bookmark. sorry for annoying, i will be back maybe with another solution, i will try to do something. Anyway thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

**Just add this line at start of class::**

```
      SharedPreferences prefs;
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

**Now initialise it in onCreate() method:**

```
      prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE, MODE_PRIVATE);
      Editor = = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

**NOW change at "onOptionSelectedItem":**

We combined the both switch.becuase it unnecessary

```
 switch (item.getItemId()) 
 { 
      case R.id.ru: 
      { 
          webView.loadUrl("https://website.com/ru"); 
           editor.putString("WEB_LINKS", "https://website.com/ru"); 
           editor.apply();

         Toast.makeText(this, "Page 1 is set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

      } 
       case R.id.en: 
       { 
           webView.loadUrl("https://website.com/en"); 
           editor.putString("WEB_LINKS", "https://website.com/en"); 
           editor.apply();

           Toast.makeText(this, "Page 2 is set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); return true; 
        } 
 }
 return true;
```

**Now do change at startWebView::**

```
 public void startwebview()
 { 
      webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); 
      webView.loadUrl(prefs.getString("name", "www.google.com")); 
 }
```

And here you are done with all things.. setting shared preference and getting it to load on start.

Comment: Sorry, but itsnot worked this is wrong code as i know
`prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE, MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor = = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();`

Comment: @alizulfuqar it is right code. it is working at my end. what error you are getting?

Comment: i edited my question, maybe after this you will understand what i mean. https://imgur.com/ebn6qB3